# Authentication Not Working with Vue JS/Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to know why authentication in Laravel does not work. The database table names are the same and still not working.

Here is the visualization of my database table "accounts":

```
|user_id | username | password|
------------------------------
|476017  | admin    | admin123|
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function sign_in(Request $request) {
        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('username', 'password'), true)) {
            return response()->json(['result' => 'Invalid credentials!']);
        } else {
            session()->put('user_logged', $request->username);
            return response()->json(['result' => 'Success', 'session' => session()->get('user_logged')]);
        }
    }
```

My user model,

```
public $table = "accounts";
    public $timestamps = false;

    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'username',
        'password',
        'user_level',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
    ];
```

And my script,

```
export default {
        name: 'SignIn',
        data(){
            return {
                user: {
                    _token:        document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
                    username:      '',
                    password:      '',
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submit(){
                // this.$emit('login', this.user)
                this.$store.dispatch('login', this.user)
                // if(isLogged){
                //     this.$router.push('/')
                // }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error says,
"Invalid credentials", it always return false.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: (1) Your password is not encrypted "admin123" and auth()->attempt() works with encrypted password use "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make('admin123')" to store password in db (2) tell me how are you using vujs with laravel are you using it with Inertia.js , stand alone with apis or embedded ?

Comment: Thanks sir @AbdulHaseebKhan , I encrypted it now and it works. I haven't tried Intertia.js, the app is only Vue and Laravel. But I might try that soon.